# String, List or Array? Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

Hi everyone could you please tell me if the following is a string, list or an array:

items = "a","b","c","d","e","f","g"

I am confused because lists or arrays would normally start with some sort of bracket? However, mine contains multiple objects but I'm not using brackets.

Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: try print(type(items)) and see for yourself!

Comment: the parentheses are optional, so items = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g") is identical to what you have. One thing to watch out for, to make a tuple with a single element, you will need item =("a",)

Answer (score 2):

It's a tuple of strings.

One way you can find out is using `type`:

```
>>> items = "a","b","c","d","e","f","g"
>>> type(items)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(items[0])
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

## It is a *tuple*

When the elements are separated by just comas it is defaulted to a tuple.

[image: Python code demo]

You can also asign them to various variables:

```
itemA, itemB = "a", "b"
```

Comment: True but was on phone so only code get an execution on screenshot and typing all is cumbersome on phone hahaha